# How to use the value of Parent's variable in Child?

Tags: c++, class

about class X

```
class X
{
protected:
    int abc=10;
public:
    X() {};
    ~X() {};
    int getABC() { return abc; }
};
```

about class Y

```
class Y : public X
{
public:
    Y() {};
    ~Y() {};

    void setABC() { abc = X::getABC(); }
};



void main()
{
    Y* b;
    b->setABC();
    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

I want to put the value of the variable abc of class X in the variable abc of class Y.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: What is `a` in your example? Also note that `b->setAofY();` is undefined behavior, even if your code would compile.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake.
i have editted.

Comment: I still do not see where `a` is defined? And `b->setAofY();` is stil UB.

Comment: i have fixed return a; -> return abc;

Comment: `void main()` is also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store a reference of `X` in `Y`.
Maybe that's what you want to do:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
protected:
    int abc=10;
public:
    X() {};
    ~X() {};
    int getAbc() { return abc; }
};

class Y : public X
{
public:
int abc;
X& x;

    Y(X& x) : x(x) {

};
    ~Y() {};

    void setAbcofY() { this->abc = X::getAbc(); }
};

int main()
{
    X* a = new X();
    Y* b = new Y(*a);
    b->setAbcofY();
    //system("pause");
    std::cout << b->abc << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i pushed upvote corretly but i dont know why downvote